# Updating documents in Azure search index one by one or in batch?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I need to update around 10 documents to Azure search index every five minutes.

So which is a better option, updating document one by one by calling async API 10 times, or calling the API only once with all 10 documents.

Note: the number of documents can be more or less (5, 20, 30...) depending on the request.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would depend on multiple factors , what's the size of the every document and type of update needed. as every https request can have a size limit and if size is big performing multiple update could be faster else single request update.

Here, you can find fields which are allowed to be update without index rebuild -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/update-index

Once above is established, application should check for concurrency if on the fly is performed and since your requirement is for every 5 minutes, concurrency check would be critical in case multiple user access the same index-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-concurrency